# unity8 with ubuntu 15.10

Tags: login, lxc, unity8

I want to use unity8 preview with ubuntu 15.10. But i am unable to log in as administrator. Only guest session is accessible. When i try to login with admin password the screen just hangs and become unresponsive. What i tried by myself is updating lxc ( sudo unity8-lxc-setup --update-lxc). This retuns the error: unable to start the container. Another command (sudo unity8-lxc-setup --rebuild) returns error: no such file or directory: '/var/lib/lxc/unity8-lxc/rootfs/etc/hostname'. I added this ppa for the unity8 - sudo apt-add-repository ppa:unity8-desktop-session-team/unity8-preview-lxc. I unable to login to unity8 with admin credentials. There is no problem with unity7 or guest session in unity8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to install the package unity8-desktop-session-mir.
Instead of unity8 lxc, it offers a fully usable session under unity8.

The only problem is that a can't install apps from the store (click errors).

Comment: This worked for me. The unity 8 interface as of now is not very useful.  Can you please explain the difference betweeen **mir** and **lxc**.